# AndEngine Augmented reality missing .jar file - Android Dependencies error

Tags: android, andengine, augmented-reality

My team is currently developing a game in Android together with AndEngine GLES2. We are using the extension AndEngine Augmented Reality. My problem is there is this error that I couldn't find any good answers to fix it. So this the error:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Asdfghjkl\workspace\nicolasgramlich-AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension-8e9a644\bin\nicolasgramlich-andengineaugmentedrealityextension-8e9a644.jar'
```

can anyone help me with this? please make it an easy-to-follow fixing guide. THANK YOU!
Actually, I copied the code of the augmented reality and pasted it in my own named class.

P.S I'm using Eclipse IDE here :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the project "internally" instead of a link to a path. Just go to where you have installed the library, then look for the jar. Asuming you're using Eclipse as IDE:

0º Check the folder libs, you should have that jar added there, remove it.

1º Copy the JAR into the folder "libs" inside your Android Project.

2º The android dependencies will be updated, you can check it from "Android Dependencies" in the project tree

Hope it helps

Comment: hi, i have the .jar file in the folder "libs" but it is also existing in the libs folder inside my project in Eclipse. should i remove it and not copy anymore?

Comment: you must remove it from the folder inside your project and then add it again copying it directly into your libs folder in the project (use CTRL+C, CTRL+V), this will update the path in your Android Dependencies. Hope it helps